# Using the dereference operator in C++ vectors

Tags: c++, vector, dereference

Whet is the difference between 1) and 2) and what will be the values of them:

```
1) double h = (*Jill_data)[5];
2) double h = *Jill_data[5];
```

when we have a `vector<double>* Jill_data`with the data: {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16}.

Comment: 1) is accessing the 5th double in the vector
2) is accessing the 5th vector<double> and derefencing it (does it even compile?)

Comment: Why those many negative votes? Why does this forum act that way? I'm really depressed asking questions here and will delete my acount

Comment: I do agree with you.

Comment: @franky I did not downvote you but questions are generally for people with problems or who are confused with something. As it stands, this question is set up more like trivia that doesn't actually work. This question also implies that you didn't try both 1 and 2 yourself to see. If you were to pose the question like "why does 1 work but 2 doesn't?" then you may have gotten better reception.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: To me, no matter in programming is trivia. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking of operator precedence in picture, as mentioned by FedeWar, the following C++ style pseudo-code may make it clearer:

```
double h1 = Jill_data . DeferenceThePointer . Access_Index_5;
double h2 = Jill_data . Access_Index_5 . DeferenceThePointer;
```

In first case, `Jill_data` will be de-referenced (pointer-indirection), which will work, since `Jill_data` is a pointer. It gives a `vector` object. Then it accesses the index, which calls `vector::operator[]` which is a valid operation. You get a `double` value.

In second case, you are accessing the 6th element (`[5]`) of `Jill_data`, which is valid, and it gives `vector`. Then you try to call `operator*` on vector, which is not implemented by `vector` class, hence you'd get "Invalid indirection" or similar error. This cannot anyway be assigned to a `double`

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. What if we use `2) double h = Jill_data[5];`?

Comment: You cannot convert a `vector<double>` to a `double`

Comment: Isn't the reason that, because `Jill_data[5]` is an address while `h` is a variable?

Comment: Irrelevant. I suggest you to brush up pointers and arrays. A positive note! :)

Answer (score 1):

The second one will not compile, the operator `[]`has an higher precedence than `*`. You can't access a method that way you should use `->operator[]`, plus you can't dereference a double number.

Answer (score 1):

1) The pointer `Jill_data` will be dereferenced and then you accessing the 5th element with `[5]`: 12.

2) Will not compile.